# Signalr in Asp.Net MVC 4 app

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, signalr, signalr-hub, signalr.client

I'm working on Asp.net MVC app, I'd like to use signalr.

Signalr to be hosted in IIS.

I added the signalr dlls and added the reference to it.

In **Global.asax**,

I put the code,

inside **Application_Start()**

```
 " RouteTable.Routes.MapHubs();"
```

I've pasted the **Global.asax**,

```
  using System;
  using System.Collections.Generic;
  using System.Linq;
  using System.Web;
  using System.Web.Http;
  using System.Web.Mvc;
  using System.Web.Optimization;
  using System.Web.Routing;

public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

        WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        AuthConfig.RegisterAuth();
        RouteTable.Routes.MapHubs();
    }
}
```

When i run the app, say, `"http://localhost:4432"`,

When I try `"http://localhost:4432/signalr/hubs"`, I get exception as follows,

```
The resource cannot be found.

Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.

Requested URL: /signalr/hubs
```

**Signalr version :** I tried with `V1.1.25 and 2.0`

Someone direct me what I should do to get it corrected?

Comment: What version of SignalR is it you are using?

Comment: I wanted to ask the same, please share your signalR version. There is a boatload of "how to get started with signalR" tutorials out there, look for one that uses the same version as you.

Comment: @SoonDead I tried, version 1.1.25 and version 2.0...

Comment: You tried adding `using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR;` to your namespaces?

Comment: @Tim B James In Global.asax?

Comment: @dani yeah add it in there

Answer (score 3):

1.write a hub extends Hub

```
public class MessageHub : Hub
```

2.check web.config

```
<system.webServer>
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
```

Comment: I tried it, still getting, exception, .....................    Server Error in '/' Application.
The resource cannot be found.
Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.

Requested URL: /signalr/hubs

Comment: try move RouteTable.Routes.MapHubs(); to the first line;i can't remenber if it has same conflict with mvc or web api route

Answer (score 2):

I tried,

```
  using System;
  using System.Collections.Generic;
  using System.Linq;
  using System.Web;
  using System.Web.Http;
  using System.Web.Mvc;
  using System.Web.Optimization;
  using System.Web.Routing;

  public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
  {
  protected void Application_Start()
   {
    RouteTable.Routes.MapHubs();
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

    WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
    FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
    RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
    AuthConfig.RegisterAuth();

}
}
```

**Put "RouteTable.Routes.MapHubs();" in the first line of Application_Start() method.**